# How to hide td by class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, html-table

I try to hide some td in table and when user click the button show them.

At first

```
<?php
   $riskCounter=0;
?>
```

Then

```
<tr class ="headMit<?php echo $riskCounter ?>">
    <th colspan="6">Title</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($actions as $action) 
{ ?>
     <tr class="body"  class ="bodyMit<?php echo $riskCounter ?>">
          <td colspan="6" style="border: 1px solid  #b4b4b4;" height="40px">
               <?php echo nl2br($action->description); ?>
          </td>
     </tr>
<?php 
} ?>
```

And after that

```
<script>
       $('.bodyMit'+<?=$riskCounter ?>).hide();         
       $('.headMit'+<?=$riskCounter ?>).hide();
</script>
```

In some place button:

```
<input type="button" class="niceButton" onclick="showMitAct('<?php echo $riskCounter ?>')" value="Show/hide" />
```

And at the end of another `foreach` which contains all of that code (and more, but I thing rest of code doesn't matter in this problem).

```
<?php
   $riskCounter++;
?>
```

Show/hide function:

```
function showMitAct(id) {
    if($(".headMit"+id).is(':hidden'))
    {
        $(".headMit"+id).show();
        $(".bodyMit"+id).show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".headMit"+id).hide();
        $(".bodyMit"+id).hide();
    }   
}
```

Ok, there is a problem. When I Click the button, `td` with `class=headMit(...)` is hiding and showing correctly, but td with `class=bodyMit(...)` is always show.

Before I have `id` instead `class`, hide/show was working correctly, but only for one of the `bodyMit`. And it's clear... One element could has got an id, but class could be bind to many elements...

Please tell me what I`ve doing wrong or where I could search fault.

Comment: Can you please put your output HTML in a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't try yours proposition, but thanks for the answer.

Problem was, that I used two times attribute class. When I change it on name, there is everything allright.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you use a MLS ID, but the class also will do.

**you can do as follows:**

```
<tr class="body"  class ="bodyMit<?php echo $riskCounter ?>" onClick:"ocultarTr('bodyMit<?php echo $riskCounter ?>'")>
```

**function javascript:**

```
function ocultarTr(idTr){
  $('.'+idTr).hide();   

}
```